# Non recursive tree in c++?

Tags: c++, tree

I found a good website for making an expression tree in c++. The `getValue` function makes perfect sense to me, but is there a way to make it non recursive? Otherwise it could create a stack overflow right?

```
double getValue( ExpNode *node ) { // Return the value of the expression represented by // the tree to which node     refers. Node must be non-NULL. 
    if ( node->kind == NUMBER ) { // The value of a NUMBER node is the number it holds. 
        return node->number; 
    }
    else { // The kind must be OPERATOR. // Get the values of the operands and combine them 
          // using the operator. 
       double leftVal = getValue( node->left )
       double rightVal = getValue( node->right ); 

       switch ( node->op ) {
       case '+': return leftVal + rightVal; 
       case '-': return leftVal - rightVal; 
       case '*': return leftVal * rightVal; 
       case '/': return leftVal / rightVal;
       } 
    }
} // end getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

No. It will raise `segmentation fault` error because there is no `NULL` check. What if `node` is `NULL` and you're accessing `node->kind`?

So first check whether `node` is `NULL` or not. Then do the rest.

```
double getValue( ExpNode *node ) {
    if (node==NULL)
        return (double)INT_MAX; //include limits.h and don't use the value INT_MAX in any node

    //rest code
}
```

If you really want to make this non-recursive, implement a stack on your own and use this stack instead of recursion.